# mysql table corrupted after migration

Tags: mysql, migration, mysqlupgrade

A migration from our old MySQL server to our new one is going wrong.

Quote from MySQL upgrade guide:

> Once a release series reaches General Availability (GA) status, upgrade within the release series (from one GA version to another GA version) is supported. For example, upgrading from MySQL 8.0.x to 8.0.y is supported. (Upgrade involving development-status non-GA releases is not supported.) **Skipping a release is also supported. For example, upgrading from MySQL 8.0.x to 8.0.z is supported.** MySQL 8.0.11 is the first GA status release within the MySQL 8.0 release series.

Old server (version 8.0.11):

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --verbose -r 2020_09_16_alldb.sql
```

New server (version 8.0.21, fresh install):

```
mysql -u root -p < 2020_09_16_alldb.sql
```

First logon was succesful. Then i attempted to restart the service, but it won't come up anymore.

```
2020-09-16T20:09:36.718949Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 1819
2020-09-16T20:09:36.725816Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-16T20:09:38.178086Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-16T20:09:38.306305Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-09-16T20:09:38.408186Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-16T20:09:38.408316Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-16T20:09:38.415771Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013143] [Server] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 51, found 49. The table is probably corrupted
2020-09-16T20:09:38.415930Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416058Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416176Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416298Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.columns_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416422Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416544Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416670Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416797Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.416921Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.417082Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.role_edges. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.417212Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.role_edges. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.417344Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.default_roles. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.417475Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.default_roles. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.417617Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.global_grants. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.417756Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.password_history. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.418298Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.global_grants. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-09-16T20:09:38.418502Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2020-09-16T20:09:38.418833Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-09-16T20:09:39.884396Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

Tried this, as recommended by others:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Result:

> The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by
> the upgrade client are now done by the server.

Please advice.

Comment: run a mysqlcheck and see what it can do after that you can try an innodb recovery

Comment: As mentioned, the service won't start, so mysqlcheck cannot be executed: mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect.

Comment: Update: used skip-grant-tables, it started. mysqlcheck reports database 'mysql' is OK (all tables), tried with --repair param, says "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair". Removed skip-grant-tables and restarted, problem still exists.

Comment: Delete mysql 8,0,21 and install it new, connect to it with workbench and use the migration tool to grap the data directly from 8.0.11

Comment: Tried to delete, `apt-get purge mysql-server`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get install mysql-server`, turns out it didn't clean up everything (install wizard didn't show up, service won't start again, error logs show same tables corrupted). Then i ran all remove commands again and `rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql`, then reinstalled again, with this as a result: Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
 mysql-community-client
 mysql-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Try to install install it in a VM and simply copy all files. That works .